# How can I enable 3D acceleration for Ubuntu as a VMWare guest?

Tags: vmware

I use Ubuntu on an iMac 8,1. I haven't been able to figure out how to enable 3d support for VMware Workstation 10. Ubuntu lists several Nvidia options but I so far they lock up the screen on log in.

What are some tools for me try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you change your machine to try and have 3D acceleration on a guest, you could try this solution. With VMware and the machine turned off, open the .vmw file that belongs to the machine you want 3D on, probably something like:

```
gedit $USER/.vmware/machines/windows7.vmx
```

And add this new line to the end of the file:

```
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = TRUE
```

Then, try to boot the machine with 3D enabled.

Comment: That worked, I also had to add how much vram to use as well. I am guessing due to the graphics card installed in this iMac.

`svga.vramSize = 67108864`

Are there added benefits to enabling Nvidia Drivers? I can't figure  out which driver to use on this machine. When I try I often get a frozen screen within a few minutes of logging into my Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know about enabling the nvidia drivers, although I've never had any problem with them. Anyway If this works it's a better solution while you get a new laptop. It worked for me in a laptop with an ATI RadeonHD.